# How to calculate night and day working hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, date-arithmetic

I have to build Excel formula which should calculate day and night working hours. We have 2 column - start and end time:

```
 start      end
16:00:00   02:00:00
```

Major condition is to separate working hours by day and night - lets assume that day hours are from 08:00:00 until 20:00:00, night working hours are from 20:00:00 until 08:00:00

I need the result into two new columns - night hours and day hours
For above example it should be:

```
day hours  = 4
night hours= 4
```

How to build more flexible and universal excel formula?

Comment: Can there only ever be a single 24hr period covered by the start and end time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add more colume with end time = minmum of 20:00:00 and the real end time.

add more colume with start time = maximum of 08:00:00 and the real end time.

now you have night time only

(do the same for day time)